# How to print all of the JSON objects inside a JSON array, without skipping the first objects?

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

So I have a this problem that when I try to print all the contents of a JsonArray, it only prints the last index repeatedly. I think maybe because JsonArray.add method adds the Json object at index 0. I'm not too sure about it but I haven't found a solution yet.

**So here is what I have so far:**

ArrayList employees contains the following objects:

1. username: username1, password: 12345678, first_name: sample1, last_name: sample1, department: sample_dept
2. username: username2, password: asdfjkl;, first_name: sample2, last_name: sample2, department: sample_dept

where in 1 is stored in index 0, and 2 stored in index 1

And here is my code:

```
JsonArray employeesJsonArray = new JsonArray();
JsonObject employee = new JsonObject();
ArrayList<Records> records = new ArrayList<>();

     for (Employee user : employees){

          employee.addProperty("username", user.getUsername());
          employee.addProperty("password", user.getPassword());
          employee.addProperty("first_name", user.getFirst_name());
          employee.addProperty("last_name", user.getLast_name());
          employee.addProperty("department", user.getDepartment());

          employeesJsonArray.add(employee);
     }

     FileWriter file = new FileWriter(FILENAME_EMPLOYEES);
     Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
     gson.toJson(employeesJsonArray, file);
     file.close();
```

**
And the result is like this: **

```
[
  {
    "username": "username2",
    "password": "asdfjkl;",
    "first_name": "sample2",
    "last_name": "sample2",
    "department": "sample_dept"
  },
  {
    "username": "username2",
    "password": "asdfjkl;",
    "first_name": "sample2",
    "last_name": "sample2",
    "department": "sample_dept"
  }
]
```

**
Where I want it to be like this: **

```
[
  {
    "username": "username1",
    "password": "12345678",
    "first_name": "sample1",
    "last_name": "sample1",
    "department": "sample_dept"
  },
  {
    "username": "username2",
    "password": "asdfjkl;",
    "first_name": "sample2",
    "last_name": "sample2",
    "department": "sample_dept"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the creation of `employee` into the loop:

```
for (Employee user : employees){ 
   employee = new JsonObject();
```

Comment: Thank you. that flew over my head.